# Reason for the murder of O-ren Ishii's parents

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-bill

The [anime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImyntxVxZyE) depicting the origin of O-ren Ishii was one of the most tragic and beautiful scenes in Kill Bill. But do we know why her parents were murdered by a Yakuza boss? It didn't make sense to me why a ganster would murder the family of a US soldier stationing in Japan.

Comment: Maybe this part of the story is inspired by the numerous articles reporting the criminal behavior of some of the soldiers stationed in Japan, such as this one for example : "US Military Personnel Have Committed Nearly 6k Crimes in Okinawa Since 1972" (https://sputniknews.com/world/201606201041602945-us-military-japan-okinawa-crimes/). The involvement of the Yakuza in the movie story could be a blind retaliation on behalf of the victim of such a crime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has never been explained, and it looks like the upcoming combined/extended "Kill Bill: The Whole Bloody Affair" also won't explain this, since the longer anime sequence seems to mostly deal with a fight between O-Ren Ishii and the "[long haired killer](http://www.slashfilm.com/kill-bill-the-whole-bloody-affair-limited-release/)":

> What’s going on with that is originally back when Kill Bill was going
>   to be one movie, I wrote an even longer anime sequence. So you see in
>   the movie [O-Ren] kill her boss but then there was that long hair guy…
>   The big sequence was her fighting that guy. I.G. [The Japanese Anime
>   Studio] who did Ghost in the Shell said we can’t do that and finish it
>   in time for your thing. And [plus] you can’t have a thirty-minute
>   piece in your movie. I said okay. It was my favorite part but it was
>   the part you could drop. So we dropped it and then later when I.G.
>   heard we were talking about doing Kill Bill: The Whole Bloody Affair —
>   they still had the script so without even being commissioned, they
>   just did it and paid for it themselves. It’s really terrific. Anyway,
>   The Weinstein Company and myself were talking about actually coming
>   out with it sometime, not before the year is out, but within the next
>   year with limited theatrical engagement as well.